Linking verbs vs negatives
Every book about writing well suggests to avoid negatives and linking verbs, and to use active verbs instead:
—Not to agree: to disagree.
—To be not pleased: to be displeased.
But sometimes when we rephrase a negative form of an acting verb we end up using a linking verb:
1–She kept explaining, though she didn’t make sense.
2—She kept explaining, though she was illogical.
Now sentence 2 has an acting verb and a linking verb. So what is preferred in writing, sentence 1 or sentence 2?

The opposite of "sense" is "nonsense," and so it would be "nonsensical" for an adjective.

I have never heard of that recommendation. What I often see recommended is to use simple and straightforward language and avoid complicated and convoluted syntax. But that doesn't mean you cannot or shouldn't use negations.
Yes, "not to agree" feels unwieldy and complicated, but "I don't agree" is just as fine as "I disagree"; similarly, "to be not pleased" isn't really proper English, but "she wasn't pleased" is just as fine as "she was displeased".
In your third example, I would slightly rephrase both sentences (to describe the person as trying to explain, which seems more fitting if her explanations don't make sense), but again both variants – with and without negation – are perfectly fine and acceptable:

She tried to explain, but she / her explanations didn't make sense.
Her attempts at an explanation were illogial / weren't logical.


Strunk & White aren't the Bible. Their advice has been criticized as often as it has been praised. But let's look at the examples they give and come to our own conclusion.
Their rule no. 12 is:

Put statements in positive form

and they give the following examples (numbering added by me):

1.a. He was not very often on time.
1.b. He usually came late.
2.a. He did not think that studying Latin was much use.
2.b. He thought the study of Latin useless.
2.a. The Taming of the Shrew is rather weak in spots. Shakespeare does not portray Katharine as a very admirable character, nor does Bianca remain long in memory as an important character in Shakespeare's works.
2.b. The women in The Taming of the Shrew are unattractive.
Katharine is disagreeable, Bianca insignificant.

In my opinion, 1.a. is funny, while 1.b. is sober and dry. Stylistically – and S&B's book is called The Elements of Style – they are not the same at all!
In my opinion, 2.a. makes the character ("him") seem affected and lazy, while 2.b. portrays someone who is goal oriented and efficient and does not waste time on useless things. The connotation of the two sentences is different!
And in my opinion, 3.a. and 3.b., mean quite the opposite: When a critic writes that Shakespeare does not portray Katharine as a very admirable character, they imply that that is what he should have done. The critic points out a failure on Shakespeare's part. When a critic writes that Katharine is disagreeable, on the other hand, the critic merely describes a fact and we might assume that that is how Shakespeare intended it and that the critic commends Shakespeare on his well-crafted portrayal of a disagreeable person.
And when a critic writes that a character does not remain long in memory as an important character, they actually mean that Bianca is an important character but that the author failed to make her as remarkable as she should be. That is the opposite of insignificant.
You may not agree with all my interpretations of the examples from Strunk & White, but I hope you can see how you need to be very careful and not assume that the positive variant of a negated sentence always means the exact same thing. Negations exist because they serve an important function. If they were superfluous we wouldn't have them.

Thank you! These are some of the books that mention these suggestions: "Style" by Joseph M. Williams; "Keys to great writings" by Stephen Wilbers; "The Element of Style" by William Strunk and E.B White.…

@Piermo I believe those books are for more formal writing than writing fiction. Fiction should generally be "colloquial" and not formal. I have found many differences with Strunk and White in best-selling fiction and in screenplays; but it obviously works there. The rules for fiction (and screenplay scene descriptions) are not quite the same. In fiction, most people are "hearing" the story in their head and trying to build a "movie" in their head of the action and characters. The writing is (with a few exceptions) much more conversational, and informal.

@Amadeus. Thank you! It makes sense.

@Ben. Thank you! I agree completely with your explanation. I have been reading many books, and the reason I asked this question is that many explanations contradict themselves. I never had a teacher, so it is hard to know which rule to follow. Thank you for your patience: it is greatly appreciate!

@Piermo Even for formal writing, blanket statements that you should ‘avoid negatives and linking verbs’ are ridiculously wrong and will lead to nothing but unnatural language. Your own three comments to this answer alone contain one negative and five linking verbs (and this comment thus far contains two negatives and one linking verb), and contorting your sentences to get rid of them would only have made it sound clumsy and unnatural (three!). Anyone who tells you to avoid natural, central parts of language when writing can be safely ignored.

@Janus Bath Jacques. Thank you!

a minor note: sometimes the meaning can be a bit different too. "I disagree" holds a stronger meaning than "I don't agree" - I can use the latter while ambigious/neutral about something, while the former expresses opposition
